# What is the single-electron concept?

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

In the paper I am reading, single electron concept, single-electron gap, single-electron properties, Single-electron tight-binding description kept coming up and I still don't understand what is this single-electron approximation or single electron concept.
It came up in this context:

> "There are several mechanisms, which could induce a single-electron gap in a bilayer sample."

and

> "Since elementary crystalline unit of graphene includes two carbon atoms A and B, the single-electronic spectrum of the Hamiltonian equation (2) consists of two bands, both of which are doubly degenerate with respect to the spin projection σ."

the paper is:' Electronic properties of graphene-based bilayer systems' https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06706

Comment: A single electron gap is often called a hole. It's a positively charged atom.

Comment: They mean non-interacting electrons.

Answer (score 1):

There are two interrelated bases for the single-electron concept.

An exact treatment of electronic properties in the condensed matter should deal with a system of $N$ interacting electrons. The exact description of a quantum state for such a system requires an antisymmetric wavefunction of $N$ electrons (fermions). However, it is possible to introduce in many ways *approximate theories* based on the simplifying assumption that the $N$ electrons wavefunction can be approximated by a [Slater determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant) or a linear combination of Slater determinants of $N$ one-electron wavefunctions for the $N$ electrons. A prototype for such approximations is the well-known [Hartee-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) approximation. Notice that the [Kohn-Sham approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations) to  Density Functional Theory also hinges on a one-electron approximation for obtaining the electron density.

On a more fundamental side, in a quantum many-body system described by the exact formalism, at least for systems like [Landau's Fermi liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_liquid_theory) (normal states of electrons in metallic systems), it is still possible to introduce the concept of *one-particle excitations*. That is, it is possible to describe the excited states of the many-electron system as if they were systems of non-interacting decaying particles with a long lifetime (the quasi-particles). A single-electron gap refers to the gap in such quasi-particle energy spectrum.